# Trying to examine an index template from elasticsearch-python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm trying to look at the contents of an index template via the python elasticsearch API.

I do this:

```
es.get_template("_template/my_template")
```

But this is all I get back:

```
{'_id': '_template/my_template',
 'found': True,
 'lang': 'mustache',
 'template': 'my_template*'}
```

How can I get back the full template contents?

Comment: have you tried without the `_template/` prefix, i.e. only `es.get_template("my_template")`?

Comment: Yes, but then it can't find the template at all.

Comment: Is it an index template or a search template? Because the `mustache` in there makes me think it's a search template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`es.get_template()` will retrieve a search template not an index template.

You need to use the `es.indices` client like this:

```
es.indices.get_template('my_template')
```